# How to change the shortcut (F) to resize the brush in sculpt mode

Tags: sculpting, shortcut

how can i change the shortcut to resize the brush in sculpt mode, i want to use the S Key instead of the F key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to go in the "Blender Preferences" and under "Keymap" select search by "Key-Binding".
[image]
Then click in the middle of the list to be able to scroll down and search for the first entry under **Sculpt**
[image]
The open one is the one for the basic resize with <kbd>F</kbd>, so you can just click on the field i marked red to then assign a new key means click on it, then press <kbd>S</kbd>.
If you want to keep the functions on the same button for the different types of resize, then i'd recommend to assign the <kbd>S</kbd> key to the 2 other "Radial Control"s. Do only click again on the same area as before and press <kbd>S</kbd>, the modifier keys in the column below like <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd> stay the same as long as you do not click them.

It should then look like this after the change:
[image]

Happy Blending

Comment: Can you map it to something which does not involve dragging the mouse?
Like when you press SHIFT+CTRL+F it will increase size by N steps?